# how to use flock() function of php in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to lock file to write from other script in Laravel 5.5. How can I do it? I have used `Storage::put()` method to write on file but it does not give file pointer so how can I use `flock()` function of PHP in Laravel.

Comment: What have you tried so far? also `Storage::put` returns path. You can use that path to `flock`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/BeatSwitch/lock-laravel
you have to install package for lock files in laravel